# Trouble trying to use JSON and JS with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get the field 'sigla' from a JSON file and put it on a HTML 'option object', but it's refusing to work as it should.. hope some of you out there can help me with that!

This is a sample of the JSON file:

```
{
  "estados": [
    {
      "sigla": "AC",
      "nome": "Acre",
      "cidades": [
        "Acrelândia",
        "Assis Brasil"
      ]
    },
    {
      "sigla": "AL",
      "nome": "Alagoas",
      "cidades": [
        "Água Branca",
        "Anadia"
      ]
    }, ...
  ]
}
```

Script:

```
<script>
$.getJSON("json/estados.json", function (data){
    $.each(data.estados, function (keyEstados, valEstados){
        var output = '';
        output += '<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>UF</option>';
        $.each(valEstados.sigla, function (keySigla, valSigla){
            output += '<option value="' + valSigla + '">' + valSigla + '</option>';
        });
        $('#selection').html(output);
    });
});    
</script>
```

Where it should fit in:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="inputBox">
      <div class="inputText">Selecione seu estado*
         <select id="selection" name="estado_php" required>
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>UF</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are fetching the `valEstados.sigla` as it was an object or an array (`$.each(valEstados.sigla)` and it has the value you need to set the `options`.

Besides that, you are setting a disabled option and the html of the select one time for each `data.estados` instead of just once.

This should work:

```
$.getJSON("json/estados.json", function (data) {
    var output = '';
    output += '<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>UF</option>';
    $.each(data.estados, function (keyEstados, valEstados) {
        output += '<option value="' + valEstados.sigla + '">' + valEstados.sigla + '</option>';
    });
    $('#selection').html(output);
});
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, silly mistake, however, this error shows on the console `SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined`, on line 107 which it's this one`$.getJSON("json/estados.json", function (data) `

Comment: Also, considering the JSON model a passed, shouldn't it be `output += '<option value="' + valEstados.sigla + '">' + valEstados.sigla + '</option>';`?

Comment: Yes. It's just `valEstados.sigla`. I've updated this. If it says '$' is not defined that means you have a trouble loading jQuery before executing this JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "developer" mode in your browser to set breakpoints in your code to debug it? E.g. on Firefox, the menu has a top level entry to "Web Developer"->"Debugger".

If you do, I think you will find have mixed up your loops. The first loop looks OK in that

```
 $.each(data.estados, function (keyEstados, valEstados){...
```

should match the list starting

```
"estados": [...]
```

However, I don't think the second loop starting

```
$.each(valEstados.sigla, function (keySigla, valSigla){
```

is needed. I think your code needs to look more like this:

```
$.getJSON("json/estados.json", function (data){
    var output = '';
    output += '<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>UF</option>';
    $.each(data.estados, function (keyEstados, valEstados){
        output += '<option value="' + valSigla + '">' + valSigla + '</option>';
    });
    $('#selection').html(output);
});
```

(not tested, but it basically gets rid of the inner loop).

Comment: Yes, I realized that a few moments after I asked; thanks for the tip; what so ever, e keep getting this error `SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined`, refering to the line `$.getJSON("json/estados.json", function (data){`; also, shouldn't it be `output  = '<option value="'   valEstado.sigla   '">'   valEstado.sigla   '</option>';`, instead of `output  = '<option value="'   valSigla   '">'   valSigla   '</option>';`?

Comment: `SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined` probably points out that you have not included jQuery so far.